# javax.transaction.Transactional vs org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, jta

I don't understand what is the actual difference between annotations `javax.transaction.Transactional` and `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`?

Is `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` an extension of `javax.transaction.Transactional` or they have totally different meaning? When should each of them be used? Spring `@Transactinal` in service layer and *javax* in DAO?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Spring has defined its own Transactional annotation to make Spring bean methods transactional, years ago.

Java EE 7 has finally done the same thing and now allows CDI bean methods to be transactional, in addition to EJB methods. So since Java EE 7, it also defines its own Transactional annotation (it obviously can't reuse the Spring one).

In a Java EE 7 application, you'll use the Java EE annotation.

In a Spring application, you'll use the Spring annotation.

Their use is the same: informing the container (Java EE or Spring) that a method is transactional.

Comment: More than that: in order to rule the universe, Spring also added implicit support for `javax.transaction.Transactional` so one could now use it also in Spring applications without any additional actions. IMO, **this was quite bad decision from design standpoint**, because out of my experience a lot of developers unconciously confuse these two in their code which leads to problems afterwards.

Comment: Furthermore, `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` offers more options (like `readOnly`, `timeout`) than `javax.transaction.Transactional`

Comment: @yura, what problems have you observed?

Comment: @LeeCheeKiam please see two answers below

Comment: "Java EE 7 has finally done the same thing" is quite misleading: this annotation exists since EJB 3.0, actually at about the same time that Spring has been having such annotation (in 1.2). Support in CDI was quite "new" when this was published (but so was CDI).

Answer (score 71):

### Declarative transaction scope

Both the Spring and JPA `@Transaction` annotation allow you to define the scope of a given application transaction.

So, if a service method is annotated with the `@Transactional` annotation, it will run in a transactional context. If the service method uses multiple DAO or Repositories, all read and write operations will be executed in the same database transaction.

### Spring `@Transactional`

The [`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation has been available since the 1.2 version of the Spring framework (circa 2005), and it allows you to set the following transactional properties:

- `isolation`: the underlying database isolation level
- `noRollbackFor` and `noRollbackForClassName`: the list of Java `Exception` classes that can be triggered without triggering a transaction rollback
- `rollbackFor` and `rollbackForClassName`: the list of Java `Exception` classes that trigger a transaction rollback when being thrown
- `propagation`: the transaction propagation type given by the [`Propagation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) Enum. For instance, if the transaction context can be inherited (e.g., `REQUIRED`) or a new transaction context should be created (e.g., `REQUIRES_NEW`) or if an exception should be thrown if no transaction context is present (e.g., `MANDATORY`) or if an exception should be thrown if a current transaction context is found (e.g., `NOT_SUPPORTED`).
- `readOnly`: whether the current transaction should only read data without applying any changes.
- `timeout`: how many seconds should the transaction context be allowed to run until a timeout exception is thrown.
- `value` or `transactionManager`: the name of the Spring `TransactionManager` bean to be used when binding the transaction context.

### Java EE `@Transactional`

The [`javax.transaction.Transactional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) annotation was added by the Java EE 7 specification (circa 2013). So, the Java EE annotation was added 8 years later than its Spring counterpart.

The Java EE `@Transactional` defines just 3 attributes:

- `dontRollbackOn`: the list of Java `Exception` classes that can be triggered without triggering a transaction rollback
- `rollbackOn`: the list of Java `Exception` classes that trigger a transaction rollback when being thrown
- `value`: the propagation strategy, given by the [`TxType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html) Enum. For instance, if the transaction context can be inherited (e.g., `REQUIRED`) or a new transaction context should be created (e.g., `REQUIRES_NEW`) or if an exception should be thrown if no transaction context is present (e.g., `MANDATORY`) or if an exception should be thrown if a current transaction context is found (e.g., `NOT_SUPPORTED`).

### Which one to choose?

If you're using Spring or Spring Boot, then use the Spring `@Transactional` annotation, as it allows you to configure more attributes than the Java EE `@Transactional` annotation.

If you are using Java EE alone, and you deploy your application on a Java EE application server, then use the Java EE `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Does the Java/Jakarta EE @Transactional annotation work for `private` methods?

Comment: Most likely, not. The transaction boundary should start when calling a service from a different layer, like the web or a scheduler.

Comment: Actually, I'm already having a delegate method in the same class with the method annotated with @Transactional. I know that I can just move the annotation to this delegate method, but I was curious about this and I didn't find anything on the web.

Comment: Private methods don't count. Only inter-services methods count for [propagation rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html).

Answer (score 68):

Another difference is how Spring handles the @Transactional annotations

- **org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional** is always taken into account
- **javax.transaction.Transactional** is taken into account only when EJB3 transactions are present. EJB3 transactions' presence is done by checking if class `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute` is available in the classpath (from version 2.5.3 to 3.2.5).
  Thus you can end up with your annotations not being taken into account if only `javax.transaction.Transactional` is in your classpath and not `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute`.
  This can be the case if you're working with Hibernate: hibernate-core (4.3.7.Final) depends on jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec (1.0.0.Final), which doesn't provide `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute`.

Comment: I think this is not an issue anymore with Spring 4.2.0: [javax.transaction.Transactional annotation is also supported as a drop-in replacement to Spring’s own annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

Comment: its not always taken, if its on a private method for example it won't be taken.

Answer (score 46):

Please be careful, (this issue happened in tomcat),

If your application is SPRING web application and you are using  Spring's transaction handling mechanism  that is  `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`, then don't mix it with javax.transaction.Transactional.

That is Always use,  `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` in a spring application consistently.

Otherwise we may end up with this error,

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: commit failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed

........

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation: [0]
```

Comment: Note: this answer is a special case of my answer