# @Transactional applicability for read methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I want to add Transactional support for my service class. If I add javax.transaction.Transactional annotation to Class which contains both read write methods how it behave?

By doing that for read methods in that class, does is make execution slow. Or does spring-boot ignore it for read methods?

Comment: Without using `@Transactional` for a read method, you might read data that's partially updated or inconsistent in some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read operations, we use org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional with parameter `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`

This just serves as a hint for the actual transaction subsystem;
     * it will *not necessarily* cause failure of write access attempts. and It will not slow execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing you need make clear that the `@Transactional` in javax and Spring is different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26387927/11827984
2. The second thing is that scope of `@Transactional`. When you write in top of a method, its scope will apply for this method, when you write in top of a class, its scope will apply for this class. (More about here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations ). And annotation has option for it @Transactional(readOnly=true) when you want for read only.